# Spring Boot Security with Jdbc Annotation

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, annotations, spring-java-config

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/icons/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/bootstrap/**", "/icons/**", "/datatables/**", "/jquery/**",
                "/font-awesome/**", "/select2/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/")
                                .permitAll()
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
                                .and().formLogin()
                                .loginPage("/userForm")
                                .usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/login")
                                .failureUrl("/userForm")
                                .permitAll().and()
                                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout").permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                "select username, password, active_status from bgtool_test_users where username = ? and active_status = 'Y'")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username, role from bgtool_test_users where username = ?")
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            ;
   }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

@Autowired
private GameFacade gameFacade;

@RequestMapping("/userList")
public String list(Model model) {
    List<User> users = gameFacade.findAllUsers();

    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    logger.debug("Users: {}", users);

    return "userList";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/userForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String userForm(Model model) {

    User entry = new User();
    model.addAttribute("userLogin", entry);
    logger.debug("Login Form");
    return "loginForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userLogin") User entry, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    System.out.println("setting status N");
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        logger.debug("Login Form validation error");
        return "loginForm";
    } else {
        entry = gameFacade.findUserByName(entry.getUserName(), entry.getPassword());
        if (entry == null) {
            result.rejectValue("password", "error.userLogin", "Username or Password incorrect !!");
            return "loginForm";
        }
        logger.debug("Login Successful", entry);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>frau</groupId>
<artifactId>bgtweb</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <derby.version>10.12.1.1</derby.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>${derby.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
         </dependency>

         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
         </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jheinzel.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <derbyHome>${project.basedir}/data</derbyHome>
                <port>1527</port>
                <database>EMDb</database>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

When i try to login, i am redirected back to loginform page. The controller method for mapping "/login" is not getting called as i am not getting my logger messages of same method in the console. 
I have checked the SQL queries.they are correct.I am unable to find what is missing.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: does this question still wait response?

Comment: @SergiiGetman : Yes I am still facing the same error even after changing the url.

Comment: @SergiiGetman : Added controller and pom.xml for more details. Can you please look into this.

Comment: all of it looks very messy. especially naming : `.loginPage("/userForm")
                                .usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/login")
                                .failureUrl("/userForm")`. login, defaultSuccessUrl, failureUrl it should be a page you shouldn't intercept it in controllers. in all case you `return "loginForm";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login page url and default success url is the same:

```
.loginPage("/userForm").usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password")
.defaultSuccessUrl("/userForm")
```

Do you understand logical chain of Spring Security? You declare pages for each authentication step, configure authentication provider that check you username and and password. it's it. So there are two possible places for error - your mapping (pages and controller) and your DB (jdbcAuthentication()).

You event don't need a controller - only pages and and security config. try to simplify your example and remove controller and debug jdbc authentication

This [example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login) show correct way of configuration

Comment: I am now using two different url for loginpage and successurl. But after successful login when i click on some link on homepage it redirects back to login page.

Comment: you have to check other aspects of your security config, possibly you don't populated SecurityContext with authentication, so you not authenticated and logically redirected to login page. check this link, but it's different question comparing to your basic issue http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication

Comment: if your problem is solved, please close question http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: sorry but my problem is not solved yet. I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: as far as i concerned your redirection is correct now. if this problem is not solved it is good idea to provide more details or even update a question

Comment: I am able to login. But my login page is called twice. I am redirecting to login page from index page so when i enter user details i am redirect to login page and second submit takes me to home page. Also, how to show the validation errors if any during login.

Comment: on login failure page